# Installing py2exe python module offline

Tags: python

I've been trying to install the `py2exe` module (for Python 3) offline (it's a stand-alone network) without without installing any dependencies first (I couldn't find a list of dependencies anywhere).

When I try to install it, it runs into a module exception :

> no module named py2exe_distutils

The file is in a `.tar.gz` format.
I use the `pip install file` in `cmd` while being in the file directory.

I would appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:
https://github.com/py2exe/py2exe/releases/tag/v0.10.4.0

this file contain the offline setup

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34D3Y.png)

Comment: Yes, i know that's the file I need. I get the error mentioned above when trying to install it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils

Comment: python setup.py install

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: all the docs are in this link docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils is pretty easy.

Comment: you use "pip install file" try to use "python setup.py install"

Comment: but there is no setup.py file. only the tar.gz file.

Comment: i should also add that it is a windows machine

Comment: 2 steps open the tar and extract

Comment: or tar -xvzf C:\PATH\TO\FILE\FILE-NAME.tar.gz -C ROUTE

Comment: On terminal 

Comment: tar -xvzf "py2exe-0.10.4.0.tar.gz" -C .

Comment: it shows up with a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2exe_distutils'" after running 'python setup.py install'

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKQ1Ph81Gps > look this video